# Trying to retrieve emails using LIKE query with MailBox (imap_tools module)

Tags: python

I would like to retrieve all "from" emails that begin with an "a" from my gmail account.

Here is what I currently have:

```
with MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login('blabla@gmail.com', 'blabla') as mailbox:
    froms = [msg.from_ for msg in mailbox.fetch()]
```

The problem is I can't find anything in documentation referring to a LIKE query. I tried this:

```
froms = [msg.from_ for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(from_="a%"))]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4

```
FROM <string>
         Messages that contain the specified string in the envelope
         structure's FROM field.
```